# Dynamically-generated table-name in PostgreSQL COPY command

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This PostgreSQL COPY command works:

```
copy tablename from E'c:\\abc\\a.txt';
```

but I want the tablename to be dynamically generated. How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to build a string, concatenating in the dynamic table name, and then use execute. Note that you escape the ' by ''. This also includes a dynamic name to save the file too. You need to replace savedir with the actual directory you are using.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamicCopy(tablename text, outname text) RETURNS VOID AS $$

DECLARE STATEMENT TEXT;

BEGIN

  STATEMENT := 'COPY (select * from ' || quote_ident(tablename) || ') to ''savedir' || outname ||'.txt''';

  EXECUTE STATEMENT;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

EDIT:

Since I first wrote this, I have discovered the format function, which I think is generally easier to read than SQL generated with the concatenation operator || and more flexible.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dynamicCopy(tablename text, outname text) RETURNS VOID AS 
$BODY$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE FORMAT('COPY (SELECT * FROM %s) TO ''savedir%s.csv''',
                  tablename, 
                  outname);
END
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See the official docs for a full discussion: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Your example-code actually demonstrates a dynamically-generated file-name rather than a dynamically-generated table-name. Also, you don't mention that your example-code specifies comma-delimited output, rather than the default tab-delimited output. (Did you copy your example-code from somewhere else?)

Comment: Ruakh, thank you for pointing out the error. Now edited with dyanmic table name and file name. Yes, it is a greatly simplified version of something I use at work -- I will be more careful in future to answer the question properly.

Comment: Jesus Christ, it took me some time to figure out the typo in quot_ident! It is quotE_ident actually! Now this one does make sense: "pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR:  42883: function quot_ident(text) does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You can copy from multi csv files to an table via shell script.

1. Make an script file: `vim csvtotable`
2. write csvtotable script. Here is my example:

   `#!/bin/sh DBNAME=postgres files=$1 for file in ${files}; do psql -d ${DBNAME} -c "\copy parent_tree(parent_id, some_text) FROM '${file}' delimiters ',' csv header" done`
3. Execute the script.

   `./csv2table "$(ls *.out.csv)"`

Obviously, Local CSV file should be **match** with table. Then It will import from csv to database tables if csv file name ending with **.out.csv**.
I am not sure csv name match is global or just at present directory match.
Reference link:
`-c` command reference https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS
chomd command: https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/
bash shanebang: https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/