# How to use \COPY command inside a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, copy

I want to export the table into a .CSV file using \COPY command. I can able to do that as a stand-alone command. I can't embed the same line inside a function in PostgreSQL. Actually that call should come from a ECPG. I chose \COPY over COPY command as I don't have super-user account! Please guide me on this.

Thanks and Regards,
Siva.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all of the `\` commands are `psql` commands. You can run `psql -E` to see what those commands expand into and get sent to the server as, but if you need a super-user account to run `COPY`, you're going to need a super-user account to do this.

Comment: It expands to `COPY TableName FROM STDIN`, but I have no idea how to **redirect** CSV file into standard input stream within function's body (as non-superuser of course).

Comment: You would probably be better served by copying your file into /tmp and asking PostgreSQL to `COPY FROM /tmp/your-filename`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using copy with plpgsql, I think this might help:

[Dynamically-generated table-name in PostgreSQL COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/in-plpgsql-copy-command-usage)

Comment: Hi, I want to use \COPY command (as I don't have super-user with me) in the STATEMENT. Is that possible? It is not allowing me inside the function. Please guide me.