# Concatenate date in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically-generated table-name in PostgreSQL COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/dynamically-generated-table-name-in-postgresql-copy-command)

I am using the copy to file function in postgresql, which works fine.

Current code looks like this

```
COPY table 
TO 'filename.txt'
```

This works fine, but I would like to add date to the filename.

So I tried

```
COPY table 
TO 'filename' || CURRENT_DATE || '.txt'
```

without success.

I have also tried putting it in a query

```
COPY table 
TO (select 'filename' || CURRENT_DATE || '.txt')
```

Anyone willing to help me out?

**EDIT**

I *think* the problem is, that the function `COPY TO` expects a string, as the destination. And I put in a query, returning a resultset...

Comment: What do you mean "without success"? Is there an error message?

Comment: Actually, I run it in an pgAgent job, and I can only see if the query ran successfully or failed.

Comment: Current date will contain 12/19/2012.  Many  operating systems don't support / in file name.  Perhaps you need to format the date differently so the / are not included.

Comment: @xQbert On my OS, current date returns 2011-12-19, which should be fine.

Comment: Maybe: Explicitly cast it to a character with desired format; to prevent any casting issues.  to_char(Current_Date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Comment: @xQbert I think the problem lies in, that the function `COPY TO` expects a string, and I run a query, returning a resultset.

Comment: I voted to close in favor of the question that Kublai Khan links to, but I realized later that that question is actually about a dynamically-generated *table-name* rather than *file-name*. (I've edited that question to be more clear.) Given that difference, I'm not sure whether it makes sense to combine the questions: they have the same solution, but for different reasons.

Comment: @ruakh: Perhaps you can add the same answer here, and add a link to the other question in your answer. That way, both questions have answers and it's not like your trying to steal any rep. :-P

Comment: @Patrick: Done. (And who says I'm not trying to steal any rep? All the rep will be mine, mine, mine! Mwa-ha-ha!)

Comment: @ruakh - You're right about the difference between the questions, thanks for noticing that. This probably shouldn't be closed then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected, the problem is that PostgreSQL is that expecting a string-literal filename, in the form `'filename'` or `E'filename'`, rather than an expression (such as a subquery) that would generate a filename as `varchar` or `text` or whatnot. So far as I'm aware, the only work-around is to dynamically generate the entire `COPY` statement, and run it in PL/pgSQL using [the `EXECUTE` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy_table_to_file(filename TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'COPY table TO ''' || filename || '''';
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
SELECT copy_table_to_file('filename' || CURRENT_DATE || '.txt');
```

A few notes:

- If desired, you can make the table-name be a parameter as well.
- As you can see from the above-linked documentation, the `EXECUTE` command supports a `USING` clause to pass in data; but I've just tested, and it seems that something like `EXECUTE 'COPY table TO $1' USING filename;` does *not* work. I assume that this is for more or less the same reason as your original question: the filename has to be specified as a string-literal, not as a substituted parameter. So, be careful with the `filename` you pass into the function, and make sure it never contains any single-quotes or backslashes or whatnot, or else you'll accidentally perform a SQL injection attack on yourself.
- You may be interested in this previous, related question: [Dynamically-generated table-name in PostgreSQL COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/dynamically-generated-table-name-in-postgresql-copy-command)

Comment: +1 Good answer. BTW I noticed this wound up getting closed in the end. I cast a vote to reopen in case you want to also. Confusing situation :\