# Postgres csv upload stored procedures

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a stored procedure for copying details from csv file to database table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION gis_portal.copycsv(IN path text) RETURNS void AS $$
COPY gis_portal.temp_excel FROM path WITH DELIMITER ','
$$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE LEAKPROOF;
```

But it is showing error as:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "path" SQL state: 42601 Character: 101

Here path is dynamic. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COPY statement doesn't support variables - only statements with plan does it. And SQL language doesn't support dynamic SQL - so you should to use plpgsql language

see [Dynamically-generated table-name in PostgreSQL COPY command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/dynamically-generated-table-name-in-postgresql-copy-command)