# I/O File Operations in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, utl-file

I am brand new to `PostgreSQL` and I need someone to point me in
the right direction on how to write the results of a function to a text
file.  Is it possible to do this within the PostgreSQL `PL/pgSQL`
language?  I have done this before in `Oracle` using the `UTL_FILE` commands
and I was hoping that `PostgreSQL` had similar functionality. Thanks in advance for any help that you can give.

Kindly provide some examples of file operations.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NP_AC015_FETCH.proc_log (P_MSG text, P_MODE integer default 1) RETURNS VOID AS $body$
    DECLARE

        V_F_IS_OPEN boolean;      --IF LOG FILE IS ALREADY OPEN THIS IS SET TO TRUE
        V_LOG_MSG varchar(32767); --LOG FILE NAME
        V_LOG_DIR varchar(30) := 'ND_GANJIS_LOG_DIR'; --LOG DIRECOTY

        vTemp UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
    BEGIN
        select get_var('GM_LOG_FILE') INTO vTemp;

        V_F_IS_OPEN := utl_file.is_open(vTemp);

        if not V_F_IS_OPEN then

          -- Log File Open
          -- 32767 IS THE MAXIMUM NUMBER OF CHARACTERS PER LINE, INCLUDING THE NEWLINE CHARACTER, FOR THIS FILE.
          vTemp := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(V_LOG_DIR, 'NIA_PLSQL_'||to_char(clock_timestamp(), 'yyyymmdd')||'.log', 'A', 32767);

        end if;

        -- LOG MSG TO BE WRITTEN TO THE LOG FILE
        V_LOG_MSG := TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss:ff3') ||' '|| P_MSG;

        --Output messages to a file
        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vTemp, V_LOG_MSG);

    --Closing Log File
    if P_MODE = current_setting('NP_AC015_FETCH.PV_LOG_CLOSE_MODE')::pls_integer and utl_file.is_open(vTemp) then

          utl_file.fclose(vTemp);

    end if;

    --HERE THE EXCEPTION PART IS NOT INCLUDED,
    --Reason： PROGRAM WILL GO ON INFINITE LOOP IF SOME ERROR OCCURS HERE, BECAUSE, EACH EXCEPTION WRITES INTO
    --LOG FILE, USING THIS PROCEDURE.
   exception

    when others then

      RAISE EXCEPTION '%', dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_error_stack||chr(10)||dbms_utility.format_call_stack, true;

    END;
$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: You might want to look up Foreign Data wrappers. There is nothing in PostgreSQL similar to UTL_FILE. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#File_Wrappers

Comment: @Jayadevan...Thanks for your reply. Could you please post sample example on how to export data to a text file using FDW ?

Comment: Looks like FDW is read-only. Does this SO answer meet your needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897085/dynamically-generated-table-name-in-postgresql-copy-command  I tested a slightly modified version of the code and it worked. Here is the code  create or replace function dynamiccopy(tablename text, outname text) returns void as 
$body$
begin
  execute format('copy (select * from %s) to ''/tmp/%s.csv''', tablename, outname);
end
$body$ language plpgsql;

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [`adminpack`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/adminpack.html) contrib module and use the function `pg_file_write(filename text, data text, append boolean)`.

Note that this function is restricted to superusers, but you can create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by a superuser that provides the necessary functionality to the users you choose.